# PHP connect to different Server Database

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I am trying to connect to different server database but I keep on getting the error message

```
$conn =  pg_pconnect("host=xx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=***** user=***** password=*****") or die ("Could Not Connect. Try again later: " . pg_last_error());
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: What error you found in pg_last_error() ?

Comment: *Can you please assist?* - Yes, I'm sure people can assist but can you please provide the relevant errors and information. Please acquaint yourself with the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of SO.

Comment: This is the error "Could Not Connect. Try again later:"

Comment: This is the error from the log   'pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "00.00.00.00", user "0000", database "P$ [Thu Sep 28 10:32:07 2017] [error] [client 00.00.00.00] PHP Warning: pg_errormessage(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet'

Comment: @AsandaLamba check port. make sure port number is correct

Comment: @BilalAmhed which port?

Comment: Connection string seems to be fine. He needs to search for pg_hba.conf errors and learn how to set it up corretly, since PostgreSQL "firewall" is refusing his connection.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" in the pg_hba table and it worked. Thanks all